# SESSION Variable Acts Differently than Typed Variable when passed as a variable in Plivo Composer package

Tags: php, session, composer-php, plivo

I have the strangest error and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I am using Plivo (a call service package akin to twilio) - on a page called direct-dial.php. To pass in a variable callerID if I explicitly state $src ='16784122312' the callerid will show up. However, if I pass in a variable that is $src = $_SESSION['phoneNumber'] which I have verified its picking up and is EXACTLY the same as explicitly typing it in it does not work. I tried to check if maybe the type was different one them (i.e. one was a string and the other an integer) no dice.

```
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$phoneNumber = $_SESSION['phoneNumber'];
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\Response;
// $dst = '16789193956';
$callerid = $_REQUEST["X-PH-Caller"];
if(! $dst)
    $dst = $_REQUEST['To'];
$src = '16784315821';
```

$src will work right now since i explicitly typed the phone number; but if I change src to $phoneNumber even though it will echo out the correct number ('16784315821') it will not display correctly on the caller_id. Could the plivo package somehow know its a session variable? Anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: your not setting it on a sub-domain are you?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no sir

Comment: Types don't matter in PHP ( loosely typed ), just FYI.  If your curious what type of variable you have then do `var_dump( $variable )`. But without the code that has `$_SESSION['phoneNumber'] = '16784315821';` or wherever it's being assigned at, it's just speculation.

Comment: let me try explicitly typing it there and see if that makes any difference (its a good idea at least)

Comment: @ArtisticPheonix whoa - so something is definitely happening because when the session is explicitly typed and passed in it works.

Comment: I thought about that, but what is the difference between `$phoneNumber` and `$src`?  seems like they are the same so one is spurious...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150209/discussion-between-usman-shahid-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: Why do you have error reporting turned off?

Comment: Because it will malform the XML if I don't and come up with errors; I messaged you a bunch in chat @AristicPhoenix

Comment: We'll I am not a fan of chat, anyway, errors are bad and should be fixed. as for malformed XML consider using output buffering `ob_start()` and `$debug = ob_get_clean()` for example and then output that into an xml tag.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - no worries on chat...umm the malformed XML came stock with the library code & are not the source of the issue...Right? How could they be?

Comment: I appreciate your responses as well

Comment: They could be the issue rather or not they came stock, for example that library may not be up to date with current Versions of PHP, errors are never good things.  I wouldn't simply ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue for anyone who specifically has a problem with plivo; the problem was that PLIVO is requesting the page from their server...

So a user makes a request from my server;
that fires plivos server to go to my page
my page looks for a session variable but since the session is set for the users computer & not plivo it doesnt find one.

Made a stopgap to query the database based off the number of who the request is calling